# Specify parameters for launcher program

Tags: google-chrome, mouse-scroll

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I have Google Chrome in my launcher and I want to add the parameter `--scroll-pixels=50` when I open it.

However, I don't get any option to set the command line options of the link.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is:

1. Remove your existing Chrome icon from the Unity launcher
2. Open the Unity Dash and make it non-maximized

[image]

3. Type "chrome"
4. Drag the Chrome icon to your desktop
5. Right-click on the Chrome icon on your desktop and choose "Properties"
6. Modify "Command" to insert `--scroll-pixels=50` before `%U` and close the window
7. Move the icon from your desktop to some folder (where it will stay)
8. Drag the icon from the folder to your Unity launcher

Comment: Wow, that definitely wasn't intuitive.  Thanks for these steps!

Comment: Would you know how to do the same for Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 7):

1. Type "chrome"
2. Drag the Chrome icon to your desktop
3. Find the name of chrome which is 'google-chrome.desktop' in my PC
4. `sudo find / -name google-chrome.desktop`, I found the location of the launch in `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop`
5. Modify the 'Exec' value
6. save and exit, `rm` the Chrome icon in your desktop

Comment: On 18:10, the file is  /usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop

Answer (score 6):

A simple way is to install alacarte, which is the old menu editor for Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install alacarte
```

Simply run it, find the shortcut (Applications -> Internet -> Google Chrome), click Proprties, and add your argument to the command.

*note, this will change the shortcut both in the dash and launcher, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore.  Adding a space to the command text field disables the "OK" button