# How to make byobu start with byobu -u on login/startup?

Tags: byobu, tmux

How do I make byobu start with unicode support by default? If I have done `byobu-enable` how I can set this `-u` option?

Answer (score 6):

Since you're asking about `-u` and not `-U`, I assume you're asking about [Byobu's](http://byobu.co) tmux backend...

In this case, you can add any additional tmux configuration options to a local tmux configuration at `~/.byobu/.tmux.conf`.  In there, you should add the following:

```
set-window-option -g utf8 on
set-option -g status-utf8 on
```

*Full disclosure: I'm the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: A recent answer says this didn't work. Any changes in the past two years?

Answer (score 0):

This might depend on how you start byobu. If you start it from the launcher like I do then you can follow the instructions in this answer to add the "-u" parameter to it: [Specify parameters for launcher program](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143422/specify-parameters-for-launcher-program) .

Note: Dustin's answer, unfortunately, did not work for me for whatever reason. If I started a non-byobu terminal it had utf8 setup correctly and if I used tmux the characters showed up, but not with byobu's terminal.

Edit: To those who edited my answer to change the lowercase 'u' to a capital 'U' that is incorrect. A capital 'U' is not a valid parameter to input when starting byobu. Here's the text in my launcher icon: "env TERM=xterm-256color byobu -u". If you run byobu -u from a new terminal (not from byobu) it works, but if you run byobu -U it spits out a clear message that capital 'U' is not a valid parameter:

> byobu -U
>
> usage: tmux [-2lquvV] [-c shell-command] [-f file] [-L socket-name]
>              [-S socket-path] [command [flags]]