# How to return to default window size of files windows in ubuntu?

Tags: windows, files

Can someone help me how to set default size of files windows when they open?

Comment: *Always* have (all) windows opened on a specific size or as an option? If the latter, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/613973/how-can-i-start-up-an-application-with-a-pre-defined-window-size-and-position/614205#614205

Answer (score 0):

nautilus may be invoked with the --geometry=800x300+200+100 for a window size of 800 wide by 300 pixels tall.  The positioning of 200 pixels X offset from right and 100 pixels Y from top, will be ignored, unless you are root (bug 1543345).  The man page for nautilus specifies the --geometry= switch, and the man page for X defines how the geometry is specified.

---

To change the parameters of a launcher icon, see [specify-parameters-for-launcher-program](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143422/specify-parameters-for-launcher-program)

Comment: OK, thanks for the detailed answer I realized default size of window is 800x300, but how can I resize it. Maybe using CCSM? But I don't know under which option.